# Store single result into variable without using foreach

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to store a single result from the database into a variable.  I tried it in different ways, but not really getting what I'm looking for.  Please see my code below: This is in the controller

```
public function create()
{
    //
    $user_id = Auth::id();

    $company_id = User::select('company_id')->where('id', $user_id)->first();

    $curriculums = Curriculum::where('company_id','=', $company_id)->get();
    dd($curriculums);


    return view('qualificationheaders.create', ['user_id'=>$user_id]);
}
```

result from the dd is:

> Collection {#2232 ▼
>     #items: []
>   }

If I replace $curriculum_id with an actual id, I get the correct result.  So I figured it's because `$company_id = User::select('company_id')->where('id', $user_id)->first();` doesn't really return a single value even though I put `->first()` at the end.  Kindly assist.  I'm a newbie to laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need make some modifications :

```
public function create()
{
    //
    $user_id = Auth::id();
// it return user not value
    $user = User::select('company_id')->where('id', $user_id)->first();   
// $user->company_id not $user
    $curriculums = Curriculum::where('company_id','=', $user->company_id)->first();
    dd($curriculums);


    return view('qualificationheaders.create', ['user_id'=>$user_id]);
}
```

**EDIT :** also you can do another thing :

```
public function create()
{
    //get company_id 
    $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;

    $curriculums = Curriculum::where('company_id','=', $company_id)->first();
    dd($curriculums);


    return view('qualificationheaders.create', ['user_id'=>Auth::id()]);
}
```